# need shell script which when detect any change/modification in my 5 rewrite rules file,will do a /etc/init.d/httpd

Tags: linux, bash, apache, shell, scripting

I need to write a shell script which when detect any change/modification in my 5 rewrite rules file,will do a /etc/init.d/httpd configtest if that gives no error it will reload apache.

Comment: You may have better answers if you show what have you written and where are you exactly stuck.

Comment: make use of `stat`, `awk` etc. commands and make a script.

Comment: check google for `inotify`.

Comment: we cannot use other utility as system lacks in cpu cores, we want to do it with shell script only

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments I'd advise you to install inotify:

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

And after that you can do something as simple as:

```
while inotifywait -q -e modify filename >/dev/null; do
   echo "filename is changed"
done
```

You can read the manpage for `inotifywait` for more info.